# Does Worker Thread mean an instance of Thread class

Tags: .net, vb.net, threadpool

I understand that there are two thread pools maintained by the CLR i.e. Worker Threads and I/O Threads.  However, after reading the following article I am a bit confused: http://nirajrules.wordpress.com/2009/09/28/net-worker-threads-io-threads-and-asynchronous-programming/.

I spoke to a more senior developer who had never heard of the term Worker Thread.  I understand Worker Thread to be synonymous to main thread e.g. when a user requests an ASP.NET webpage, then a worker thread is created.  Therefore if 20 users accessed the website concurrently then there would be 20 active Worker Threads.  If 20 users accessed a multi threaded application that created three threads (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), then would there be sixty active threads?..  However after some further research I have discovered that:

```
1) Worker Thread is synonymous to Background Worker (not main thread)
2) The term Worker Thread means nothing to some people
```

Therefore my question is: Is Worker Thread synonymous to Thread (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?) or does it mean main thread?

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1524249/what-is-a-worker-thread-and-its-difference-from-a-thread-which-i-create

Comment: I don't think there's an official definition for a worker thread but I've always understood it to explicitly NOT be the main UI thread.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's just a very layman (non-technical) way to understand the things but I found it very easy way to understand the concept of worker threads.

## General Definition:-

A “worker thread”  is just  a thread which runs to perform  some background work on order of his boss(we can call it “client” ) and update work result to boss.

## Technical Definition:-

A worker thread is usually defined as a thread that gets activated on clients requests.

## Example 1:

1-  We have pizza store, where there are 10 guys who are expert in preparing a delicious pizzas. These are called as "worker threads".

2-  We have a guy who receives the orders from customers. That guy is called as “client”. Whenever a new order comes, one of "worker thread" starts preparing the pizza and update to client once the pizza is prepared.

3-  When there are less than 10 orders, some of the workers just sit ideal.

4-  When there are more than 10 orders, the orders are just put into waiting queue.

## Example 2:

1-  There is an app server that listens to port 8080.

2-  A request comes in on port 8080.

3-  A listener thread (it’s called as “client”) takes that request and dispatches it to a “worker thread” that completes the request. There is actually a pool of “worker threads”  maintained ( many objects of the “worker thread” program) on app server.

4-  If two requests come in at the same time, two worker threads are assigned and the task is executed simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding a worker thread is not a UI thread. It allows code to be run without locking up the user interface (UI). Any code run on the UI thread forces the UI to become unresponsive until the code has completed. There are workarounds to this (eg Me.Update()) but good practice is usually to run anything that's going to take more than a second on a non UI thread.

One possible difference between a Worker Thread and a Thread is that a Thread doesn't necessarily report on it's progress or report when it has finished to the UI thread. I hope this helps.